# LSZ reduction formula relation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, scattering, path-integral, s-matrix-theory

LSZ formula gives a relation between the scattering amplitudes and correlators as

$$\langle f |i \rangle = (-i)^{m+n}\int \Pi_{i=1}^m d^4x_, e^{ik_i'x_i (\Box_{x_i} -m^2)}\Pi_{j=1}^n d^4x_, e^{ik_j x_j (\Box_{y_j} -m^2)}\langle 0 |T[\phi(x_1)...\phi(x_m)\phi(y_1)...\phi(y_n)] | 0 \rangle$$

but also the difference between the initial and final creation operators goes as

$$a^{\dagger}(k, +\infty)- a^{\dagger}(k, -\infty) = -i\int d^4x e^{ikx}(\Box_x-m^2)\phi(x)$$

It looks like as if the LSZ reduction formalism is kind of related to the time ordered product of the second equation but I don't know why since the second equation is just a difference while

$$\langle f |i \rangle = \langle 0 |a(k'_{1}, +\infty)...a(k'_{m}, +\infty)a^{\dagger}(k_{1} -\infty)...a^{\dagger}(k_{n}, -\infty) |0 \rangle $$

Any clarification is appreciated

**Partial Answer**

Having defined

$$a^{\dagger} = -i\int d^3x e^{ikx}\partial_{0}\phi$$

it's not hard to derive the LSZ formula but still I fail to see the relation with the difference of the creation operators

Comment: Are you following a reference? Which page?

Comment: Not a particular book but lecture notes of my professor